# Loop or Recursion in SQL or use Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, loops, recursion

Suppose I have the following table:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 9 | 13 | 14 | 14 |
| 8 | 12 | 13 | 12 |
| 7 | 9 | 12 | 10 |
| 6 | 8 | 11 | 8 |
| 5 | 8 | 10 | 6 |

Here A-B-C-D are shopping carts. I want to buy the items in the cart. The prices for the items are in each row. For instance, shopping cart A has 6 items with prices (10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5).

I only want to purchase an item in a given cart if there isn't a cheaper item in another cart, otherwise I want to purchase the item from the other cart. As I purchase each item, I'll mark it as purchased. Also each shopping cart has a different purchase capacity. For A, the max I can purchase is 5, for B its 6, for C its 4, and for D its 1.

**Cart A is the anchor so if A reaches capacity, we stop.**

So this is how it would go.

Buy:

1. 5 from A
2. 6 from A
3. 6 from D - D reaches capacity after this purchase
4. 7 from A
5. 8 from A
6. 8 from B
7. 8 from B
8. 9 from A - A reaches capacity

Since A reached its capacity, it would end here.

How would you go about doing this in SQL. I think I can use a loop, but I have read that SQL is meant to be set-based for efficiency. What I am trying to do seems to require a loop or recursion. Is that the right approach, should I be using Python for this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Updated the tag, using mysql. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify why and when the process ends? You wrote "Since A reached its capacity, it would end here.", but A reached its capacity 2 steps before that.

Comment: Sorry about that, the process should end at step 8. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @RareWiz ok, check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this pretty easily by unpivoting, enumerating the rows, and filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select cart, val,
             row_number() over partition by cart order by val) as seqnum
      from ((select 'A' as cart, A as val from t) union all
            (select 'B' as cart, B from t) union all
            (select 'C' as cart, C from t) union all
            (select 'D' as cart, D from t)
           ) t
     ) t
where (cart = 'A' and seqnum <= 5) or
      (cart = 'A' and seqnum <= 6) or
      (cart = 'A' and seqnum <= 4) or
      (cart = 'A' and seqnum <= 1)
order by val, cart;
```

Note:  Depending on the database you are using, there might be simpler ways to unpivot.

Comment: Thanks for this. To be clear, what I am really looking is a way to compare the minimum price in each cart and buying the cheaper item. Then doing the process again until cart A reaches capacity. 

This particular script is just returning the cheapest items from each cart, I believe but not doing any comparisons to decide what to purchase.

Comment: @RareWiz . . . I think that is the same process.  This chooses the items "in order" by price, which is what your question is showing.

Comment: Got it, makes sense. I ran this with a tweak. I changed the where clause to look at all carts not just cart A, I think it may have been a typo. It returns 16 rows (5+6+4+1). How can I limit it to just 8 rows, since cart A reaches its capacity at that point? Thanks for your help!

Comment: when did mysql get `partition` features?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
with tab as (
select 'A' as cart, A as value from table
union
select 'B', B from table
union
select 'C', C from table
union
select 'D', D from table
)
select * from (
    select tab.*, 
    case 
        when 
            sum(case when cart = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) over(order by value) < 5
            or sum(case when cart = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) over(order by value) = 5 and cart = 'A'
        then 1 
        else 0 
    end as selected
    from tab
) items
where items.selected = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Python solution, you can use a `while` loop:

```
from collections import deque
full_data = [{'a': 10, 'b': 14, 'c': 15, 'd': 16}, {'a': 9, 'b': 13, 'c': 14, 'd': 14}, {'a': 8, 'b': 12, 'c': 13, 'd': 12}, {'a': 7, 'b': 9, 'c': 12, 'd': 10}, {'a': 6, 'b': 8, 'c': 11, 'd': 8}, {'a': 5, 'b': 8, 'c': 10, 'd': 6}]
data = {i:deque(sorted([j[i] for j in full_data])) for i in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
s, m = [], {'a':5, 'b':6, 'c':4, 'd':1}
while m['a']:
   a, _, _ = min([(a, b[0], i) for i, [a, b] in enumerate(data.items()) if m[a]], key=lambda x:(x[1], x[-1]))
   s.append((a, data[a].popleft()))
   m[a] -= 1
```

Output:

```
[('a', 5), ('a', 6), ('d', 6), ('a', 7), ('a', 8), ('b', 8), ('b', 8), ('a', 9)]
```